# What's a boot loader for UEFI?

Tags: uefi, boot-loader

I know MBR bootloaders, the MBR bootloader must switch a computer to the protected mode (as rule) and pass the control to OS kernel, for example [here](http://3zanders.co.uk/2017/10/13/writing-a-bootloader/). But what's UEFI bootloader? As I've read UEFI is a some microsystem (like BIOS but it does more stuffs). But what does bootloader do in UEFI case?
I tried to read about it on [OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/UEFI) but I got almost nothing, unfortunately... Maybe due to my poor English.

Can someone explain me general steps of a trivial UEFI bootloader to load OS kernel and pass control to it? I couldn't find samples.

**P.S.** Of course, all operating systems are different same as computer architectures but I mean x86_64 architecture with 64-bit or 32-bit OS kernel.

Comment: https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, thank you, I'll try to learn this source code

Comment: UEFI firmware is capable of reading from a FAT filesystem (the EFI System Partition) and can load EFI programs from it and execute them. So, by compiling the Linux kernel into a UEFI executable, the firmware can load and start it. End of story.

Comment: UEFI is not a boot loader, but a more advanced replacement for BIOS. Grub2 is boot loader as is systemD boot used by some distributions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFIBOOT & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition & https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface

Comment: @oldfred I know this is not boot loader, I mean how does boot loader look with UEFI?

Comment: I really only know grub2 and it is the same. Grub has versions, grub-pc for BIOS based PC booting and grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI with 64 bit systems. UEFI & BIOS/CSM/Legacy are not compatible as they write the system info differently onto the drive. But if you really wanted different boot on a drive, you can but only can then boot from UEFI menu. Screenshots of secure boot settings Asrock, Asus, HP, Acer
https://neosmart.net/wiki/disabling-secure-boot/

Comment: @Шах, здесь вовсю вылезает разница между boot loader (которым может выступать сама UEFI-прошивка) и boot manager (которым она обычно может и не выступать); вдобавок к ссылке на refind предложу свою любимую по этой теме: rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html

Comment: @oldfred there's a somewhat more thorough page on disabling sekirboot over at http://rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable while at that...

Comment: See also: https://systemd.io/BOOT_LOADER_SPECIFICATION/  All USB external drives boot from /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi. And internal drives often have that file also, but with Windows bootx64.efi is a copy of Windows .efi boot file and grub makes bootx64.efi a copy of shimx64.efi (for secure boot  with grub2 boot loader but works with secure boot off also)

Answer (score 1):

There can be no extra bootloader (or bootmanager) with UEFI as the firmware itself plays bootloader role (at least to run some other bootloader/bootmanager); most of those I've seen so far lack bootmanager ("boot menu: ...") role -- or play it badly though.

A boot*loader* can load and run the next-stage executable (another bootloader, bootmanager, a kernel, or e.g. memtest86); in UEFI SecureBoot case it's also held responsible for running the binary's signature validation hooks within firmware.

A boot*manager* can read some preconfigured menu or scan for available filesystems and boot targets (or do both like [refind](http://rodsbooks.com/refind/) does) so as to present the user with a menu to choose from those.

In "trivial" case, one can start a Linux kernel compiled with `CONFIG_EFI_STUB=y` and placed as `\EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` into an x86_64 system's FAT32 EFI System Partition directly by UEFI firmware although distros don't seem to support that, leaning for grub2 instead.

Artem gave you almost the right link, the one you actually seem to need is Rod's excellent [Managing EFI Boot Loaders for Linux: Basic Principles](http://rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html)

PS: возможно, пригодится [ALT Rescue](http://altlinux.org/rescue) :)

Comment: See http://jdebp.uk./FGA/bootstrap-programs.html .  And http://jdebp.uk./FGA/efi-boot-process.html of course.